# how to load images from local and external server and load into the webview in iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c, image, webview

I need to get the images from local and external server and load them into the webview.

Can anyone suggest me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Why to load the images in the webview when u can show the images in the UIImageView, heres the code to do the same

In order to display an image from a server to the image view you may refer to the [this](http://iphonebyradix.blogspot.com/2010/12/load-image-from-server-in-imageview.html) link

and in order to display the image from  a server to the web view you can refer to the following code

```
NSURL *u = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://thenextweb.com/apps/files/2010/03/google_logo.jpg"];

 NSURLRequest *r = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:u];

 [mywebview loadRequest:r];
```